# how would you go about to recreate this edge texture? (sawed off wooden edge)

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor, displacement, pbr

I have not been using blender for quite a while and tried to recreate this texture with displacement maps, but have not gotten that far. How would you proceed? I have tried weight painting and using voronoi textures but didn't get the results I was hoping for!
Thanks in advance[image]

this is my last render:
[image]

UPDATE: This is my updated render. Still trying to figure it out, especially the authentic sawed off texture.

[image]